# Use tbs to merge multiple records from sql to single block with mergeblock

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am using template docx and tbs template engine to generate document by values from sql. I want to load multiple records from sql dynamically to table I created in template docx which have single block called vm.productname. I want to make rows created dynamically and print for how many records available in sql array.But, failed to load multiple records dynamically.

This is how template.docx look like. [image: template.docx]

```
<?php
include_once('../tinybutstrong/tbs_class.php');
include_once('../tinybutstrong/plugins/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');
//$tbs  = new clsTinyButStrong("##","##");
$tbs    = new clsTinyButStrong;
$tbs->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
$tbs->LoadTemplate('file_tobe_tested/1_template_defaultdelimiter.docx');

$db_name    ="template";
$db_con     =new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=template", 'root', '');

$query_get_companyinfo="select * from company where company_name='ABC Sdn Bhd'";
$data_get_company_info=get_data_from_sql_assoc($query_get_companyinfo,$db_con);

$tbs->MergeField('vs.company_name',$data_get_company_info[0]['company_name']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.company_address_street',$data_get_company_info[0]['company_address_street']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.company_address_zipcode',$data_get_company_info[0]['company_address_zipcode']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.company_address_city',$data_get_company_info[0]['company_address_city']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.company_address_state',$data_get_company_info[0]['company_address_state']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.company_address_country',$data_get_company_info[0]['company_address_country']);

//assume customer_name is adam

$query_get_customerinfo="select * from customer where customer_name='Adam'";
$data_get_customer_info=get_data_from_sql_assoc($query_get_customerinfo,$db_con);

$tbs->MergeField('vs.customer_name',$data_get_customer_info[0]['customer_name']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.customer_address_street',$data_get_customer_info[0]['customer_address_street']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.customer_address_zipcode',$data_get_customer_info[0]['customer_address_zipcode']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.customer_address_city',$data_get_customer_info[0]['customer_address_city']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.customer_address_state',$data_get_customer_info[0]['customer_address_state']);
$tbs->MergeField('vs.customer_address_country',$data_get_customer_info[0]['customer_address_country']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");

//get customer_id from $data_get_customer_info
$customer_id=$data_get_customer_info[0]['customer_id'];

$query_get_products ="select product_name from product where customer_id='".$customer_id."'";
$data_get_products  =get_data_from_sql_assoc($query_get_products,$db_con);

$tbs->MergeBlock('vm.product_name',$data_get_products);
//$TBS->MergeBlock('blk_res',$result);

$output_file        ='output_1'.$date.'.docx';
$tbs->Show(OPENTBS_FILE,$output_file);

print "<a href=\"$output_file\">$output_file</a><br>";

function get_data_from_sql_assoc($query,$db)//fetch associative
    {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);  
        $statement->execute();
        $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

I get this error when I excute the code

> TinyButStrong Error in block's definition [vm.product_name...]: at
>   least one tag corresponding to tr is not found. Check opening tags,
>   closing tags and embedding levels.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change `[vm.product_name;block=tr]` to `[vm.product_name;block=tbs:row]` in template.

Ammended template:
[image]

In php code, I change `$tbs->MergeBlock('vm.product_name',$data_get_products);` to

```
$tbs->MergeBlock('vm',$data_get_products);
```

Since I have another variable under vm, that is vm.product_price, I have included product_price records to $data_get_products. Then, I merge block using vm as block name so that both variable will be replaced with respective records. This solved my issue.

---

Alternatively , `,*` should work for multiple records. But I failed in making it run.

Method MergeBlock() enhancement in  v3: [from this link](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/support/tbs_v3_whatsnew.htm)

- Now you can makes the method to return the full merged data by adding
  '*' as a block name to merge.

  `Example : $data = $TBS->MergeBlock('blk,*','SELECT id FROM table_a');`

Answer (score 0):

Your template seems OK.

The inner XML is probably split in an invisible way because of the Spelling and grammar checking. It is sometime also split because of invisible formatting change in the text, or too many user modifications on the text.

Hopefully the solution is simple :

1. Select the text of the TBS field (that is "[vm.product_name;block=tr]")
2. Cut it, and then past it again using the `paste without formating` clipboard option
3. Select again set Spelling and grammar to `Do not check spelling and grammar`.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried. Red line disappear from that text.But, still showing same error.

Comment: I tried change text to [vm.product_name;block=tbs:row]. This able to create rows according number of products in array. But display without value.